# Should I use Gzip in this case?

Tags: gzip, cpu-usage

I have a restful java api that provides data to a Node.js client (that gzip data to users). The question is, **If they are running in the same machine**, should I Gzip the data from the java api to the node.js application?

I'm asking this because this case, I dont have to worry to network latency, but Gzip compression may increase CPU utilization.

Does it worth use gzip this situation?

Answer (score 1):

If the objective is to increase speed of the overall system, then using gzip to transfer across processes boundaries would not be very useful, particularly if the message size is small enough to fit within memory. If the message is too large to fit in memory, and some paging overhead is incurred, the benefit of gzip may be greater but still not anywhere near enough to justify using it. Gzip only makes sense when the speed of compression is significantly greater than the speed of communication. This is usually not the case with inter-process communication (even if it incurs pagefault overhead.)